# Class and Function in PHP

Tags: php

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=350');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
</script>

<a href="popupex.php" onclick="return popitup('popupex.php')">Link to popup</a>
```

the top code is my index, where in you can see a **Link to a popup** link
and when you click that a simple form will rise, the form has 2 textbox and one submit button this is the code for the form **popupex.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
print"<form action='func.php?add/inside_add' method='post'>";
?>
<input type='text' name='ok'><br>
<input type='text' name='notok'><br>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Question:** why the code in my func.php is not running? simply because of error? and can some explain the error and also give solution?

this is my **func.php**

```
<?php
function goback()
{
window.history.go(-1);
}


class add{
    function inside_add(){

    goback();
    }
}
?>
```

what im hoping in this function , is when i click the button in my **popupex.php** it will go back in the form **popupex.php**. thx

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is a javascript function `window.history.go(-1)`

use `header('Location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` for PHP to return to the previous page.